# Google Maps Freezing when zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I modify script from here [add label overlay Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554435/add-label-overlay-google-maps/30560310#30560310)

I just wanted to show some of the labels , not all.

**code snippet:**

```
// LABEL /// 
var label = new Label({ map: map, text: markerJson[i].kapasitas }); 
if (markerJson[i].gardu != 'T') { 
    label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position'); 
} else {} 
// label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position'); 
// LABEL ///
```

but when I zoom in - out, the map will error like freezing and marker will disapear.

**result jsfiddle :**

[map no freezing + all label](http://jsfiddle.net/o9dp8jhv/3/)

[map freezing + some label](http://jsfiddle.net/o9dp8jhv/2/)

---

and why if I load 1000++ data with label, map will lag, if just marker and infowindow map is fine. (I do not want to use map cluster)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't going to set the position of the label, don't create it.

Change this:

```
    /// LABEL ///
    var label = new Label({
        map: map,
        text: markerJson[i].kapasitas
    });
    if (markerJson[i].gardu != 'T') {
      label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');
    } else {}
```

To:

```
    /// LABEL ///
    if (markerJson[i].gardu != 'T') {
      var label = new Label({
        map: map,
        text: markerJson[i].kapasitas
      });
      label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');
    } else {}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9dp8jhv/4/)