# How to add text description to point google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to add to maps the point's description (red text), like the image bellow. I can't find how to do it on the google maps API.

[image]

Comment: related question: [Add marker with Google Maps Javascript API to look exactly as marker that were added in maps.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165971/add-marker-with-google-maps-javascript-api-to-look-exactly-as-marker-that-were-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, you want to put a custom text on your map. You could check for Google Maps Custom Overlays property [here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) also other people answered this question by giving examples in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554435/add-label-overlay-google-maps) and [here(this includes working example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953922/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-text-on-google-maps-api-v3).
Hope these helps!